# Elasticsearch : Using boost in span_query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use boost in span_or query, but get an error.

Here is my elasticsearch code and error returned

```
GET /addr/_search
{
  "query":{    
    "span_near": {
        "clauses" : [
            { 
              "span_or": { 
                "clauses" : [
                  {
                    "span_term": {
                      "poi": {
                        "value": "long",
                        "boost" : 2.0
                      }
                    }
                  }, 
                  { 
                    "span_term": {
                      "poi": {
                        "value": "mei"
                       }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            { "span_term" : { "poi" : "da" } }
        ],
        "slop" : 1,
        "in_order" : true
    }
  },
  "sort": [{"freq": {"order": "desc"}}]
}
```

```
root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "span_or [clauses] as a nested span clause can't have non-default boost value [2.0]",
        "line": 15,
        "col": 19
      }
    ]
```

so is it possible to use boost in span_or or span_near query？just like it works in bool query

Answer (score 1):

the boost parameter is only allowed for outer span queries...
As described here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html

It is only allowed to set boost on an outer span query. Compound span queries, like span_near, only use the list of matching spans of inner span queries in order to find their own spans, which they then use to produce a score. Scores are never computed on inner span queries, which is the reason why boosts are not allowed: they only influence the way scores are computed, not spans.

```
GET /addr/_search
{
  "query":{    
    "span_near": {
        "boost" : 2.0 <-------------------- here //untested
        "clauses" : [
            { 
              "span_or": { 
                "boost" : 2.0 <-------------------- here //untested
                "clauses" : [
                  {
                    "span_term": {
                      "poi": {
                        "value": "long",
                        "boost" : 2.0 <-------------- not allowed
                      }
                    }
                  }, 
                  { 
                    "span_term": {
                      "poi": {
                        "value": "mei"
                       }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            { "span_term" : { "poi" : "da" } }
        ],
        "slop" : 1,
        "in_order" : true
    }
  },
  "sort": [{"freq": {"order": "desc"}}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## About Span query scoring:

1. **It is only allowed to set boost on an outer span query.**
2. **Scores are never computed on inner span queries**

> Compound span queries, like span_near, only use the list of matching
> spans of inner span queries in order to find their own spans, which
> they then use to produce a score.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html